# I am creating a calculator and trying to access the input box so I can append the numbers when the user types in. I can't access the input's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I can't access the inputs innerHTML to change it everytime a user types in a number.
I tried by accessing the value, it didn't work.
how do I change the value of the input element after the user clicks a number button.

```
let inputText = document.querySelector("[data-input]")
let number = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]")
let clear = document.querySelector("[data-clear]")
let deleteOperation = document.querySelector("[data-delete]")
let operation = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]")
let equal = document.querySelector("[data-equal]")



number.forEach(button =>{ 
    button.addEventListener('click',()=>{ 
     inputText.innerHTML = button.innerHTML 
})
})

operation.forEach(operand =>{
 operand.addEventListener('click',()=>{ 
      alert("operation  pressed")
})
})
```

```html
<div class="calculator-grid">
  <input data-input type="number" name="input" id="input" placeholder="">
  <div class="number-container">
  <div data-clear class="oper ">C</div>
  <div data-delete class="oper ">DEL</div>
  <div data-operation class="oper ">%</div>
  <div data-operation class="oper ">÷</div>
  <div data-number class="num">7</div>
  <div data-number class="num">8</div>
  <div data-number class="num">9</div>
  <div data-operation  class="oper multiply">*</div>
  <div data-number class="num">4</div>
  <div data-number class="num">5</div>
  <div data-number class="num">6</div>
  <div data-operation class="oper add">+</div>
  <div data-number class="num">1</div>
  <div data-number class="num">2</div>
  <div data-number class="num">3</div>
  <div data-operation class="oper minus">-</div>
  <div data-number  class="num">0</div>
  <div data-number  class="oper">.</div>
  <div data-equals class="oper" id="equal">=</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `inputText.value` can be used to get and set text of the input field. The only issue is that it will be string, so you may want to parse it to convert to number, for example `parseFloat(inputText.value)`.

Comment: don't you have any error messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputText.value` can be used to get and set text of the input field, see [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) API.

The only issue is that it will be string, so you may want to parse it to convert to number, for example `parseFloat(inputText.value)`, see [parseFloat docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for details.

When each number is pressed you can add one number to existing text:

```
number.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputText.value += button.innerHTML
    })
})
```

Implementing operators is a bit complicated, maybe you can post another question to cover that.

Here's working code (ignore the CSS, it's just for example):

```js
let inputText = document.querySelector("[data-input]")
let number = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]")
let clear = document.querySelector("[data-clear]")
let deleteOperation = document.querySelector("[data-delete]")
let operation = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]")
let equal = document.querySelector("[data-equal]")



number.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputText.value += button.innerHTML; // append number to existing value
    })
})

operation.forEach(operand => {
    operand.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert("operation  pressed, input value is "+ parseFloat(inputText.value))
    })
})
```

```css
/* some styling just for this example */
.number-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.number-container > * {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-grid">
    <input data-input type="number" name="input" id="input" placeholder="">
    <div class="number-container">
        <div data-clear class="oper ">C</div>
        <div data-delete class="oper ">DEL</div>
        <div data-operation class="oper ">%</div>
        <div data-operation class="oper ">÷</div>
        <div data-number class="num">7</div>
        <div data-number class="num">8</div>
        <div data-number class="num">9</div>
        <div data-operation class="oper multiply">*</div>
        <div data-number class="num">4</div>
        <div data-number class="num">5</div>
        <div data-number class="num">6</div>
        <div data-operation class="oper add">+</div>
        <div data-number class="num">1</div>
        <div data-number class="num">2</div>
        <div data-number class="num">3</div>
        <div data-operation class="oper minus">-</div>
        <div data-number class="num">0</div>
        <div data-number class="oper">.</div>
        <div data-equals class="oper" id="equal">=</div>

    </div>
</div>
```